# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find a value for null

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalargumentexception

getting the runtime error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find a value for null not understand clearly where the bug is. tried different of code but not understand where the bug is. just converting few units.

```
 public class UniqueConverter extends Fragment {

    private Spinner fromDetails, toDetails;
    private EditText fromInput, toInput;


    public static UniqueConverter setArguments(int position) {
        UniqueConverter uniqueConverter = new UniqueConverter();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        uniqueConverter.setArguments(args);
        return uniqueConverter;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uniquelayout, container, false);

final String[] temperatureform, weightform;
 temperatureform = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.temperatureform);
        weightform = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weightform);

    onInitVies(view);
    int position = getArguments().getInt("position");
    String ifrom = (String) fromDetails.getSelectedItem();
    String rto = (String) toDetails.getSelectedItem();
    Double inp;
    double out = 0;

 switch (position) {
            case 0:
                setAdapter(temperatureform, "Celsius", "Fahrenheit");
                TemperatureConverter con = new TemperatureConverter();
                TemperatureConverter.Units fromUnit = TemperatureConverter.Units.fromString(ifrom);
                TemperatureConverter.Units toUnit = TemperatureConverter.Units.fromString(rto);
                inp = Double.valueOf(fromInput.getText().toString());
                out = con.TemperatureConvert(fromUnit,toUnit,inp);
                break;
            case 1:
                setAdapter(weightform, "Kilograms", "Grams");
                WeightConverter converter = new WeightConverter();
                WeightConverter.Inus fromInus = WeightConverter.Inus.fromString(ifrom);
                WeightConverter.Inus toInus = WeightConverter.Inus.fromString(rto);
                inp = Double.valueOf(fromInput.getText().toString());
                out = converter.WeightConvert(fromInus, toInus, inp);
                break;

 final double finalOut = out;
        fromInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    if (!fromInput.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    {
                        toInput.setText(String.valueOf(finalOut));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        toInput.setText("");
                    }

                }
            });


            return view;

    }


    private void setAdapter(String[] spinnerItems, String fromDefaultText, String toDefaultText) {
        fromDetails.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerItems, fromDefaultText));
        toDetails.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerItems, toDefaultText));
    }

    private void onInitVies(View view) {
        fromDetails = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.fromSpinner);
        toDetails = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.toSpinner);

        fromInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fromInput);
        toInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.toInput);
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 01:58:38.255 6246-6246/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.cloudicalabs.converters, PID: 6246
03-16 01:58:38.255 6246-6246/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find a value for null
03-16 01:58:38.255 6246-6246/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.cloudicalabs.converters.datahandlers.TemperatureConverter$Units.fromString(TemperatureConverter.java:27)
03-16 01:58:38.255 6246-6246/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.cloudicalabs.converters.fragments.UniqueConverter.onCreateView(UniqueConverter.java:74)
03-16 01:58:38.255 6246-6246/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
03-16 01:58:38.255 6246-6246/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
03-16 01:58:38.255 6246-6246/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
```

Comment: From where getting `ifrom ` and `rto ` ?

Comment: edited code, its take item from spinner

Comment: you are calling fetching string before calling `setAdapter` method i.e y it is returning null value...first call `setAdapter` and then fetch string from it...

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, Set adapter before retrieving the selected item for both spinners. 
You can write that switch case just after this line:

```
int position = getArguments().getInt("position");
int position = getArguments().getInt("position");
Double inp;
double out = 0;
switch (position) {
....
}
String ifrom = (String) fromDetails.getSelectedItem();
String rto = (String) toDetails.getSelectedItem();
```

Hope this simplifies !